# How to set number of minor tick marks for only one but not both the axes?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Consider the following code:

```
using Plots
gr()
x = 1:10
y = rand(10)
plot(x, y)
xaxis!(minorticks=10)
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

There are 10 minor tick marks on **both** x- and y-axis. I like to set the number of minor tick marks on only the x-axis, leaving the y-axis with no minor ticks. In the same way, I could ask how I could the number of tick marks on the y-axis independently of x-axis.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xminorticks` and `yminorticks` keywords seem to work, e.g.

```
using Plots
plot(1:10, xminorticks=10)
```

[image: Plots.jl plot with x minor ticks only]

Comment: `xaxis!(xminorticks=10)` also works (though it is redundant). This seems like a bug where `xaxis!` should perhaps have prepended `x` to the option, but doesn't?

Comment: Thanks for this! Are `xminorticks` and `yminorticks` documented?

Comment: They don't seem to be; my usual go-to is the "attributes" section of the Plots.jl documentation, but I don't see these there

Comment: Yeah, not documented officially. I've checked before posting, but these keywords do get mentioned, albeit very sparsely, on Google, but only when I knew what to search for.